# iis 7.0, module order change

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

"the entries cannot be reordered because one or more of them have been locked in the parent file "

in iis 7.0 manager when i try to change the order of modules in my application it gives this message.

how can i change the order of the modules ? is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you do it on Server level instead of site level?

Comment: What do you mean? pls give more detail.

Comment: Instead of setting the order of modules on the Site level in the IIS manager. Do it on the Server level.

Comment: What if a module that we want to order doesn't exist on the server level, but where it exists we want it to execute before modules that do exist on the server level?

Comment: Yeah, my custom module in a subfolder needs to run first.  In fact, if it chooses to handle the request, it's the only one that should run at all.

Answer (score 2):

To change the order of modules for a site you first need to unlock the affected modules on the server level. Because you don't really know which modules are affected, I usually unlock them all. The easiest way to do this is with a PowerShell script (if you are still on IIS7, you need to download the [PowerShell IIS snapin](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/powershell)).

Save the following into text file: unlock-modules.ps1

```
 Import-Module WebAdministration

 Get-WebConfiguration `
 -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' `
 -filter "system.webServer/modules/add" -recurse | `
 where {$_.PSPath -eq 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -and $_.Type -eq ''} `
 | foreach {         
     $filter = "system.webServer/modules/add[@name='" + $_.Name + "']"     
     Remove-WebConfigurationLock -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter $filter -verbose
 }
```

Open a PowerShell prompt as elevated administrator and run the script.

The script loops through all the modules at server level. Usually only the native modules (with and empty 'type' property) are locked. Unlock them all.

Now you can make changes to the order of the module at site level.

Be careful when the re-ordering, if you change the order of some of the system modules, IIS may no longer work in the expected way.

Also remember, that if you make changes to the modules at server level, the site will no longer inherit these and you have to apply them to the site level as well.

Comment: Is it possible to change the execution order from a command line or powershell?

Comment: The script helped me, but after running it I get "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)" often when I navigate in IIS config snap-in, and each time when I go to authentication.

Comment: But a system reboot seems to have solved the problem.